# Consistent, Unique Value based on Object-Values

Tags: c#, hash

I have an Object, which needs a Unique Value to identify itself. This unique value has to be always the same if the Object-Content is the same, so generating a UUID or GUID on creation is not possible.

I thought about hashing the Object based on its members and found some ideas on how to write a hash-method, but how can I assure, that my own HashCode-Function never collides with another Object by chance?

Comment: the point of hashing its to form groups of more or less similar objects to enable faster queries on large data. Calculcating a different hash for every item is pretty pointless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hash-codes are not *intended* to be unique - that isn't what they do or how they work. They are *frequently* different when objects are different, but *that's not the same thing*. If you want reliable non-colliding identity, there are a few common options:

0. if the data is coming from an RDBMS or similar; get the RDBMS to manage and issue identity tokens, and use those
1. use the object reference itself; this is small, opaque, and is guaranteed to work correctly (on 32-bit this is the same size as `int`; on 64-bit it is twice that, but... meh, it is usually fine)
2. use an external identity issued by some mechanism of your devising, typically an atomically incrementing integer that is either a dictionary lookup, or the offset into a vector of the values, or simply a static interlocked-add field that acts like a counter; this *does* prompt some questions about what to do when the number of allocations during an application lifetime goes near the billion mark (and you start running out of unique `int` values), assuming you can't simply reset the identity allocator periodically (i.e. "wipe the universe", arena-allocation style

Note that you *could* combine any of these with the "hashcode" concept, if you control the object such that the hashcode *returns* the external identity